# Custom validation in laravel for updating the table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-validation

I'm trying to validate the update method in laravel 5.4 Following is my validation code:

```
$data = $request->only('id', 'name', 'number', 'logo', 'email', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'country', 'type', 'tier', 'is_client');
$company = Companies::find($request->id);
Validator::make($data, [
    'name' => 'required|max:255',
    'email' => 'required', Rule::unique('companies')->ignore($company->id),
    'address' => 'max:255',
    'city' => 'max:255',
    'state' => 'max:255',
    'country' => 'max:255',
]);
```

But this validation breaks, suppose in update method I pass name empty it not throwing error code 422 
[image: Error]

It is showing this error and I'm unable to catch the error and display in span tag

**Update**

As suggested in answers I tried adding the validate and trying to check I'm getting following error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

Following is my updated code:

```
$data = $request->only(['id', 'name', 'number', 'logo', 'email', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'country', 'type', 'tier', 'is_client']);
$company = Companies::find($request->id);
Validator::make($data, [
    'name' => 'required|max:255',
    'email' => 'required', Rule::unique('companies')->ignore($company->id),
    'address' => 'max:255',
    'city' => 'max:255',
    'state' => 'max:255',
    'country' => 'max:255',
])->validate();
```

Even if I don't make my `$data = request->only()` an array I get the same error.

[image: Validation error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only creating `Validator`, not validating the data. Have to call `validate` function.

```
Validator::make($data, [
    ...
])->validate();
```

**UPDATE**

For error `Trying to get property of non-object`. Notice you are passing email validation rules as string where it should be array

`'email' => ['required', Rule::unique('companies')->ignore($company->id)],`

If error still exists. Check the variable `$company` if its contains data.

Comment: `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: @NitishKumar What is the line 46 in `CompanyController` ?

Comment: `'email' => 'required', Rule::unique('companies')->ignore($company->id),`

Comment: @NitishKumar Updated the answer. please check

Answer (score 0):

`->only()` needs an array of parameters:

```
$request->only(['id', 'name', 'number', 'logo', 'email', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'country', 'type', 'tier', 'is_client']);
```

You were passing several arguments, instead.

Comment: `Trying to get property of non-object`